# Monte Carlo simulation of a financial market

Tags: simulation, finance

I'm fairly new to *Mathematica* and i want to review the average prices of this model. In order to do that i need to perform a Monte Carlo simulation on my financial markets model:

```
P[t_] := P[t] = P[t - 1] + μ*ED[t - 1] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03]];
ED[t_] := ED[t] = WC[t]*DC[t] + WF[t]*DF[t];
DC[t_] := DC[t] = b (P[t] - P[t - 1]);
DF[t_] := DF[t] = c (F - P[t]);
WF[t_] := WF[t] = 1/(1 + Exp[-β*a[t]]);
WC[t_] := WC[t] = 1 - WF[t];
a[t_] := a[t] = α0 + αn*(WF[t - 1] - WC[t - 1]) + αp (P[t - 1] - F)^2;

μ = 0.01;
β = 1;
b = 0.01;
c = 0.01;
α0 = 0;
αn = -0.4;
αp = 1;

F = 1;
P[0] = F;
P[1] = F;
P[2] = F;
P[3] = F + 0.01;

WF[1] = 0.2;
WC[1] = 0.8;

logprices = Table[P[t], {t, 1000, 6000}];
logreturns = Differences[logprices];
abslogreturns = Abs[logreturns];
Dis[t_] := Dis[t] = Abs[P[t] - F];
SumDis = Table[Dis[t], {t, 1000, 6000}];
Mean[SumDis]
Mean[logprices]
Kurtosis[logreturns]
```

`P` = Price, `ED` = excess demand, `DC/DF` = demand, `WC/WF` = weights, `a` = influences of weights,
`F` = fundamental value, `dis` = distortion

A single run is supposed to yield the average price, the average distortion and the kurtosis of the logreturns. `P`, `DC/DF` and `WF/WC` will be plotted using `ListLineplot`.

I want to run this about 2000-5000 times and compile the resulting 2000-5000 average prices and distortions in a list or something along those lines so i can average them to see what a change of a variable does to those.

I read the *Mathematica* documentation on how to perform a Monte Carlo simulation, but I couldn't see how to transfer it to my model.

I tried the table function but the only result I achieved is `{Null}`.

My question is: how do I set this up correctly?

Comment: Why did you delete the code in your question?

Comment: I rolled previous revision back as this question makes no sense without code sample.

Answer (score 6):

You use memoization in your code. In some cases that may be quite useful. Personally, I use it rarely, because it mixes data and operations on that data in a rather unfavorable way: After a single run of your simulation, you have to delete almost all you definitions. So the life cycle of the memoized data is pretty short; in the end it will be tiny fractions of a second. 
Moreover, you plan to produce huge loads of numerical data; these can be most efficiently stored and accessed in a simple array. Since you want to perform lots of simulations with many different parameters, you might also want decent performance of the code. Thus, I compiled your code into the following library function:

```
cf = Compile[{{noise, _Real, 1}, {F, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real},
   {α0, _Real}, {αn, _Real}, {αp, _Real}, {β, _Real}, {μ, _Real}, {WF1, _Real}, {WC1, _Real}},
  Block[{P, ED, DC, DF, WF, WC, a, n},
   n = Length[noise];
   P = Table[0., {n}];
   ED = Table[0., {n}];
   DC = Table[0., {n}];
   DF = Table[0., {n}];
   WF = Table[0., {n}];
   WC = Table[0., {n}];
   a = Table[0., {n}];
   P[[1 ;; 3]] = {F, F, F + 0.01};
   WF[[1]] = WF1;
   WC[[1]] = WC1;
   Do[
    P[[i]] = P[[i - 1]] + μ ED[[i - 1]] + noise[[i]];
    DC[[i]] = b (P[[i]] - P[[i - 1]]);
    DF[[i]] = c (F - P[[i]]);
    a[[i]] = α0 + αn (WF[[i - 1]] - WC[[i - 1]]) + αp (P[[i - 1]] - F)^2;
    WF[[i]] = 1./(1. + Exp[-β  a[[i]]]);
    WC[[i]] = 1. - WF[[i]];
    ED[[i]] = WC[[i]]  DC[[i]] + WF[[i]] DF[[i]];
    , {i, 2, n}];
   {P, DC, DF, a, WF, WC, ED}
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
```

Now you can run 5000 simulations with 6000 iterations each within a second with

```
n = 6000;
m = 5000;
μ = 0.01;
β = 1;
b = 0.01;
c = 0.01;
α0 = 0;
αn = -0.4;
αp = 1;
F = 1.;
WF1 = 0.2;
WC1 = 0.8;
noise = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03], {m, n}];
data = cf[noise, F, b, c, α0, αn, αp, β, μ, WF1, WC1];
```

In order to interpret the output: `data` has dimension `{m,7,n}`. You access `{P, DC, DF, a, WF, WC, ED}` (in that order) of the `j`-th iteration in the `i`-th simulation with `data[[i,All,j]]`.

Comment: I tried your solution but i got the following error                                                                   
Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function.

CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::nocomp: A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers.

Comment: Aha. You have no C compiler installed. That somehow tells me that you are using windows. You have two options: For very fast execution, install a C compiler, e.g. cygwin. If you are lazy but somewhat more patient, just change `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"`. On my system, the difference is a factor five in execution time.

Comment: I changed it WVM since i don't get mathematica to recognize cygwin.
Another question would be how do i get access to all iterations of P?

Comment: The list of all `P` in the `i`-th simulation is `data[[i,1]]`.

Comment: And see here (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html) for more information on C compilers that are supported.

Comment: Ok but is there a way to access a list of all P from every simulation? SInce this is essential for my work

Comment: Yes, that's `data[[All,1,All]]`.

Comment: I know you should avoid thank you comments but thank you so much. You were such an incredible help for me. Just thank you so so much.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad to hear that you make progress!

Comment: I guess i have to ask another question how do i work with `data[All,1,All].` ?For example i want to use the mean function over all P.

Comment: Ah, `A=data[All,1,All]` is a rank-2-tensor (matrix). You get the mean of rows with `Mean@A` and the mean of columns with `Mean /@ A`. I warmly advice you to read the documentation on `Map`. The mean over all entries of `A` is `Mean[Mean /@ A]` or `ConstantArray[1., Dimensions[A][[1]]].A.ConstantArray[1., 
   Dimensions[A][[2]]]/Times @@ Dimensions[A]`.

Comment: When i try to get the mean i get the error message `Mean::rectt: Rectangular array expected at position 1 in Mean[1]` and the Output looks like this `Mean[{{{1., 0.966386, 0.964785, 1.01256, 0.981866, 0.996495, 0.963478, and so on`

Comment: Oh, sorry. It should be `A = data[[All, 1, All]];` with double brackets.